# MVC internet application(iis express worker process is closing)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, oauth, iis-express

I have created `ASP.NET MVC` project using `internet template`. Then I have enabled external(facebook) authentication in `AuthConfig` file. Now when I run my project and get authenticated with `facebook` it is working just fine, but the problem is that associated `iis express worker process` is just closing approximately within 1 minute and `VS` debugging stops(as if I manually press the Shift+F5). I am getting no errors at all. This doesn't happen when I run the project with `Chrome` or if I just don't authenticate when using `Internet Explorer`. It only happens in `Internet Explorer` when I am authenticating with `facebook`.

Can anyone suggest what is going on?

Several observations:

- when I am authenticated with local account problem doesn't occurs.
- when I am authenticated with `facebook` it redirects to
  `http://localhost:27264/#_=_`. May be `#_=_` this is the problem?